# Running Java Mail samples

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm new to Java. I feel pretty dumb right now. I'm just trying to run an example program and I'm not having any luck. At this time, I'm trying to just run the [JavaMail sample app](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) from the command line. From my understanding, I should be able to do this:

```
java -Dmail.imap.sasl.enable=true -Dmail.imap.sasl.mechanisms=XOAUTH2 -Dmail.imap.auth.login.disable=true -Dmail.imap.auth.plain.disable=true -Dmail.imap.ssl.enable=true -Dmail.debug.auth=true msgshow -D -U [EmailAddress] -P "[AccessToken]" -T imap -H imap-mail.outlook.com -f INBOX 1
```

However, when I enter that command into the terminal window on my Mac OS X machine, I get an error that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: msgshow
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: msgshow
```

I feel so bad, because I don't know how to even compile this thing. I opened up the directory in IntelliJ IDEA and hit the Build -> Rebuild Project. I'm just not having any luck. How do I get this sample app to run?

I sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

msgshow isn't going to do anything.  You have to refer to the actual location of the file on your computer, otherwise it will just be refering to a local destination.

Comment: Refer to the location of what?

Comment: The location of the file.  Like this: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\file.extension